# how to make zip files (produced by a self-made maven plugin)from target folder end up in the local repository?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, mojo

I am creating my own maven-environment-plugin that creates and bundle resources for a predefined folder structure for each environment defined in the configuration. The plugin is outputting the folder structure and resource in a zip file and placing it in the target folder.

**Questions**:

- How can I make my plugin work like the `maven-assembly-plugin` so my output to target folder also ends up in my local repository when I use 'mvn install'?
- Do I need to mark it or something? Its automaticallly doing it when the `maven-assembly-plugin` is used.
- How does `maven-assembly-plugin` manage to make sure of this?

I am using mojo for my plugin development.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>dk.kmd.devops.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>envconfiguration-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <environments>
            <environment>${env.local}</environment>
            <environment>${env.dev}</environment>
            <environment>${env.t1}</environment>
            <environment>${env.t2}</environment>
            <environment>${env.p0}</environment>
        </environments>
        <sourceConfigDir>${basedir}/src/main/config</sourceConfigDir>
        <zipEnvironments>true</zipEnvironments>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generateEnv</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach (that's the correct terminology in this case) the new artifact (the generated zip file) to the build as part of its *official* artifacts.

This is basically what the [`attach-artifact`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) goal of the `build-helper-maven-plugin` does:

> Attach additional artifacts to be installed and deployed.

From [its official examples](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html), the attach goal:

> Typically run after `antrun:run`, or another plugin, that produces files that you want to attach to the project for install and deploy.

The *another plugin* in this case can be the plugin you developed. Hence there are two solutions to your case:

- Configure this plugin to attach the generated artifact as a further `pom.xml` configuration, or
- add to your plugin the functionality to automatically attach the generated file

The second case can be covered via Maven API, using the [`MavenProjectHelper`](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProjectHelper.html) and its [`attachArtifact`](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProjectHelper.html#attachArtifact(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) method.

In your mojo, you can import is as a component via:

```
/**
 * Maven ProjectHelper
 */
@Component
private MavenProjectHelper projectHelper;
```

Then use the aforementioned method:

```
projectHelper.attachArtifact(project, "zip", outputFile);
```

You should probably already have the required Maven dependency providing it, but just in case it would be [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-core/3.3.9):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that the artifact will be attached to the build as an additional artifact via a [classifier](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates), that is, a suffix to the default artifact name differentiating it from the default artifact and making it unique as output of the build.

---

As a reference to real example and to further answer your (last) question, check [this](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/search?p=1&q=attachArtifact&utf8=%E2%9C%93) query on the GitHub `maven-plugins` repository, checking for the `attachArtifact` string, you will see it used in a number of Maven plugins, among which the `maven-assembly-plugin`, for example [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/9a1cbfcc47048c46455ca4990440a87d75989d00/maven-assembly-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/assembly/mojos/AbstractAssemblyMojo.java#L487) in the [`AbstractAssemblyMojo`](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/9a1cbfcc47048c46455ca4990440a87d75989d00/maven-assembly-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/assembly/mojos/AbstractAssemblyMojo.java) class.

Comment: Great!! Thx a lot :) I will definitely go for the second case. Want to make my plugin independent of other plugins. I will be back